# Find the complex roots of$ z^4+2z^2+2=0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I don't know how to find all the complex roots of $z^4+2z^2+2=0$ Can someone explain how to solve this step by step?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$(z^2+1)^2+1=0$$
$$z^2+1=\pm i $$
Now solve it by square root method.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $w=z^2$ and transform the equation to $w^2+2w+2=0$, which you can solve by the usual quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

take $x=z^2$
and solve
$$
 x^2+2x+2=0
$$than backsubstitue the two roots: $z^2=x_1$ and $z^2=x_2$ give four roots of the quartic.